# Searching for Browser Compatibility Tool

Tags: testing, browser, compatibility

Hay I am using IE Tester for browser compatibility, but its only for Internet explorer. Is there any Browser Compatibility  Tool for all most all commonly used browsers.

Answer (score 1):

See http://spoon.net/browsers/

Browsers bundled as virtualized apps. It's much cleaner than IE Tester. IE Tester actually does not work like real IE6/7/etc. Moreover is breaks your installed IE.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this website to check it will generates screenshots of how websites appear at 800x600 and 1024x768 resolution in six commonly used web browsers.

http://browsershots.org/